# swagger UI displays "ERROR" and complain about schemaValidationMessages

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

for me Swagger works absolutely fine but at the end of the web page "Error" button displays.
On click "Error" button it displays

```
{
"schemaValidationMessages": []
}
```

Could you suggest me how can I avoid "Error" button and make it to "Valid" button ?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors on the Console or Network tabs in the browser dev tools? Do you host Swagger UI [dist assets](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) yourself, or do you use Swagger UI bundled with your API framework?

Comment: Yes there were few errors on consol regarding CSP but i was able to solved it by degrading few gems (gem 'rswag-api', '2.4.0', gem 'rswag-ui', '2.4.0') to older version, thanks for pointing the issue